# dynamic page size depend on inner menu items height

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i have Menu which have dynamic items collapsed By default i am trying make page height change with changing in items collapse status bu using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function fun() {
          var iFrameID = document.getElementById('wrapper');
          if (iFrameID) {
              // here you can make the height, I delete it first, then I make it again
              iFrameID.height = "";
              iFrameID.height = iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
          }
      }
```

and Using This Method In

```
     <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="fun()" data-target='#<%# Eval("HeaderMenuId")%> '><i class="fa fa-fw fa-arrows-v"></i> <%# Eval("HeadItemText")%>  <i class="fa fa-fw fa-caret-down"></i></a>
```

i get error

```
Cannot read property 'document' of undefined
```

Comment: The dynamic menu probably is not made inside an iframe !

Comment: This code here is to find the iframe inside height, not the height of a div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; iFrameID.contentWindow is undefined.

You are selecting the wrapper (suppose div) not the frame or iframe.
Only frame tag and iframe tag have contentWindow property.

Solution:

```
var iFrameObj = document.getElementById('iFrameId');
iFrameID.height = iFrameObj .contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Comment: Your answer Is right (worked) but didn't give my goal